# Python 2.7 - IPython 'raw_input' and appending to a list - adds 'u' before each item

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, ipython

I'm using `Python 2.7` on Mac OSX Lion.  I'm using `IPython` with the `Pandas 0.11.0`, `Numpy` and `Statsmodels` packages.

I'm writing a function that allows the user to do logistic regression on a file, specifying which variables to be used in building the model, which should be transformed into dummy variables and which variable should be the independent variable.

When I do the following, for instance:

```
 cols_to_keep = []
 print (df.columns)
 i = eval(raw_input('How many of these variables would you like to use in logistic regression?: '))
 while i != 0:
    i = i - 1
    print (df.columns)
    addTo = raw_input('Enter a variable for this list that you would like to keep and use in logistic regression.: ')
    cols_to_keep.append(addTo)
```

I end up running into problems down the road.  Specifically when I ask the user to specify the dependent variable from a list and then need to take that variable out of the list of training variables:

```
print (df.columns)

dependent = raw_input('Which of these columns would you like to be the dependent variable?: ')
training.remove(dependent)
```

I found, after inserting a print statement, that the variables added to the list of training variables, looks like this:

```
('these are the traing variables: ', ['access', u'age_age6574', u'age_age75plus', u'sex_male', u'stage_late', u'death_death'])
```

It appears that a `u` has been placed before each user-specified variable.

My question is: why is this and how do fix/get around this issue so that, when the user specifies the dependent variable, it is actually removed from the list.  This also occurs in all other instances where a user specifies a variable and it is added to a list, creating confusion if I ever need the user to observe the list.

Comment: leave it as unicode, you may prettify the way you print it otherwise it's not a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are just unicode strings, as opposed the byte strings. There is nothing wrong, and the content of the string is not affected.  The `u'text'` is just so that you can tell the difference between byte strings and unicode strings in Python 2 when you look at the repr.  If you print the string, you will see no difference. This is reversed in Python 3, where `"text"` means a unicode string, while `b"bytes"` means a byte string.

If you really want to coerce them to bytestrings (unlikely), you can do:

```
def ensure_str(s):
    if isinstance(s, unicode):
        s = s.encode('utf-8')
    return s

s = ensure_str(raw_input("prompt >"))
```

Comment: Yep!  That does it!  Thanks for your help!